# How do I take a question offline?

Tags: discussion

I want to contact a person who was helping me - how?
I could not find way to email or message the person. They were helpful. Our question was getting too long for work on the main page seciton.

Comment: If your question is running too long, consider that it's possibly too broad. Mostly this may mean that a question should  be multiple questions or that the question is not specific enough. Try to specify questions to the single obstacle which is blocking you from progressing. Skip code & comments that are not related to the issue and stay focused. When you have multiple issues, ask multiple questions.

Try to always ask the right question.  Many ask for help on their code and requirements while they should be asking where to find the documentation or how to use a specific salesforce feature.

Comment: Another reason to keep your questions online is so others can find the question and answer and it may help them as well. When you go one on one, then nobody else benefits.

Answer (score 2):

If your questions goes too long, you get the option to continue over chat.

Comment: How do I continue over chat?